# How to find the items in the optimal solution of the knapsack problem using dynamic programming?

Tags: c, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I want to find which items are eventually chosen in the optimal solution of the knapsack problem using the method of dynamic programming.
This is my interpretation so far...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int getMax(int x, int y) {
    if(x > y) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return y;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    //the first element is set to -1 as
    //we are storing item from index 1
    //in val[] and wt[] array
    int val[] = {-1, 100, 20, 60, 40};  
    int wt[] = {-1, 3, 2, 4, 1};   
    int A[] = {0,0,0,0,0};    
    int n = 4; //num
    int W = 5;//cap  
    int i, j;


    // value table having n+1 rows and W+1 columns
    int V[n+1][W+1];

    // fill the row i=0 with value 0
    for(j = 0; j <= W; j++) {
        V[0][j] = 0;
    }

    // fill the column w=0 with value 0
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        V[i][0] = 0;
    }

    //fill the value table
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(j = 1; j <= W; j++) {
            if(wt[i] <= j) {
                V[i][j] = getMax(V[i-1][j], val[i] + V[i-1][j - wt[i]]);
            } else {
                V[i][j] = V[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //max value that can be put inside the knapsack
    printf("Max Value: %d\n", V[n][W]);


    //==================================find items
    int n1,c;
    n1=n;
    c=W;
    int A2[n1][c];

    while(c>0){

        if(A2[n1][c]==A2[n1-1][c]){
            A[n1]=0;
        } else {
            A[n1]=1;
        }

        n1=n1-1;
        c=c-wt[n1];

    }

    printf("Final array of items: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d",A[i]);
    }
} // end of main
```

And this is the output:

```
Max Value: 140
Final array of items: 0001
```

This string of ones and zeros is meant to be the finally chosen items, but from the solution this seems to be wrong!

I followed this algorithm:

```
While the remaining capacity is greater than 0 do
If Table[n, c] = Table[n-1, c] then
Item n has not been included in the optimal solution
Else
Item n has been included in the optimal solution
Process Item n
Move one row up to n-1
Move to column c – weight(n)
```

So, is this algorithm wrong / not suitable for this method, or am I missing something?

Comment: The code that computes the max value appears to work, since 140 is indeed the max value. The code that finds the items declares an array `A2[n1][c]`, but doesn't store anything in that array. You should probably be using the `V` array in that part of the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Please follow the basic principle, "make it easy for others to help you".  Fix the indentation and spacing; use descriptive variable names; present your entire algorithm, not a central portion with undefined references.

Comment: @user3386109 The V array?

Comment: Do you mean the A?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake ...

Comment: I ll try that..

Comment: I think you would need to declare `getMax` outside of `main`.  You cannot define a function within another function in standard C.

Comment: I have no issue with that.I threw 'getMax' out but nothing changed,But since i changed the array to 'V' i get '0110' witch again is not correct!